# how many states can i create in AnimationController base layer in unity3d?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

In fact, i have 700 avatar animations of sign language. i want theses animations to play when specific word is entered. For this, can i create 700 animation states? is it possible? if not possible please give another solution.

Comment: I don't now if there is any limit to the amount of states in an animator. But it could get very cluttered and confusing. Only make sure to also think about the [performance](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MecanimPeformanceandOptimization.html)

Comment: For not needing to connect them all by transitions in the animator [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.CrossFadeInFixedTime.html) could be really helpfull